# What is the best MVC3 solution structure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, projects-and-solutions

I plan to start a MVC3 project, and we hope this project will be the blueprint of MVC3 project for our company, please see below initial ideas:
[image]

[image]

Guys, please help share your ideas and best practise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to have a look at **Onion Architecture** *(image copyright: [Jeff Palermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com))*. I had some crazy depencdencies, too, (see [Castle Windsor: Register components across multiple projects in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244416/castle-windsor-register-components-across-multiple-projects-in-solution)) that can be expressed cleaner using Onion Architecture.

1. [The Onion Architecture : part 1](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)
2. [The Onion Architecture : part 2](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-2/)
3. [The Onion Architecture : part 3](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-3/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My team at work uses a very similiar architecture  - the primary difference is that our "object module" sits behind WCF.  It's been a great advantage for us to have objects returned from WCF as it's taken very little effort to consume data in our MVC, Silverlight, and Windows apps.